# Clearing multiple text input boxes with one name

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I have several text input boxes, and i have a clear button, they all share the same name and i wish to clear them all using one function, and this be done without ID's as that takes up too much space 
my code thus far looks like this:

```
var Id;
var Name;
function Check(id, name)    {
Id = document.getElementById(id);
Name = document.getElementById(name);
if (Id.value == id) {
    Name.checked = true;
    alert('correct');
    return;
} else  {
    Name.checked = false;
    alert('incorrect');
}
}
function ClearP()   {
document.getElementsByName("input").innerHTML = '';
}
```

my html looks like this

```
<div class="content">
                    <div class="main_story" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
                        <p class="sentence">the word to go here -></p>
                        <input id="here" name="input" class="sentence" type="text" size="7">
                        <p class="sentence">is here</p>
                        <button style="float:right" id="correct" onClick="Check('here', 'aShow');">Correct?</button>
                        <input style="float:right" name="aShow" id="aShow" type="checkbox" value="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="main_story" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
                        <p class="sentence">the word to go here -></p>
                        <input id="you" name="input" class="sentence" type="text" size="7">
                        <p class="sentence">is you</p>
                        <button style="float:right" id="correct" onClick="Check('you', 'bShow');">Correct?</button>
                        <input style="float:right" name="bShow" id="bShow" type="checkbox" value="">
                    </div>
                    <button onClick="ClearP();">Clear</button>
                </div>
```

all help is much appreciated :) thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function ClearP(){
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++)
        inputs[i].value = '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give all of them another class (something like "clearable", perhaps?), then find and clear all items with that class.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), and something like this:

```
$('[name="input"]').val("");
```